# Regular Expression(^string\s\w+) in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'd like to know how to search using regular expression.

**this is my code**

```
import re
data = "python one test code"
p = re.compile("^python\s\w+")
```

**result**

```
print(p.findall(data))    
['python one']
```

**The result I want to get is as below**

```
print(p.findall(data))
['python one test code']
```

**I can get the above result if as below**

```
p = re.compile("^python\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+")
```

but I don't want to repeat "\s\w+" like as "^python\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+"

How can I get the result using * or + in "\s\w+" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^python(?:\s\w+)+
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/8S5lkl/1)

1. `^python` string starts with python
2. `?:`  the () group will not be captured
3. `\s\w+` will match a space and the immediate word
4. `(?:\s\w+)+` the outer plus will match all occurrence of no.3 where + means one or more

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
p = re.compile("^python[\w\s]*")
```